# how understand if a segment is inside a lissajous curve

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

i am a programmer and not a math guru, but i like geometry. so if i'm not accurate in math terminology or i have folly question please sorry me.

i'm drawing with a programming language the lissajous curve ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve ), sampling 100 points.

i want to consider all segments formed by any two points. how can i understand if the segment is "inside" (i don't know how to explain it with right math words) the trigonometric curve?

here is an example:
[image]

the black segment is "outside", the blue one is "inside".

EDIT:
- segment P1-P3 is considered "outside"
- in wikipedia there is a general form but i consider only closed curve where a/b is rational

Comment: What about a segment such as from p3 to p0, which has parts both inside and outside the curve?

Comment: How high are the frequencies you're expecting for your Lissajous curves?

Comment: @Isaac: Do you mean from p3 to p1?

Comment: @Américo: er, oops... p3 to p1 is more likely to work than p3 to p0, yeah... it isn't entirely clear to me that p3 to p1 is actually both inside and outside, but clearly p3 to p0 is entirely inside.

Comment: segment p1-p3 is considered outside

Comment: @nkint: Do you restrict the problem to the closed curves? According to Wikipedia these curves are closed only if a/b is rational.

Comment: ohu, yes! just updated